# Cannot reference a Long Text Area data type into a Formula Text field

Tags: formula, admin, long-text-area, isblank

Is there a way I can reference a long text area field to a formula text field?

I just need to check if my LongText field value is blank or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't reference a long text area field.
[Formula Field Limits and Restrictions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_field_limits.htm&type=5)

> You can’t use long text area, encrypted, or `Description` fields in formulas.

There is also a [very old Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjTTUAZ/text-area-long-formula-support) about it